# Web API VS 2012 Authentication

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

Is the Web API authentication template available for Visual Studio 2012?

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET Web API 2 and the *Individual accounts* feature is part of MVC 5 so, if you want to use these features, you have to use MVC 5. Fortunately, you can use it with Visual Studio 2012, just read [this article](http://rionscode.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/using-asp-net-mvc5-within-visual-studio-2012/) about how to do that.

To summarise the information, in November 2013, the .NET team released the **ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 Update** for Visual Studio 2012. You can click [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532) or [here](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids) (or read and get some links in [Scott Hanselman's blog article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleasedASPNETAndWebTools20122InContext.aspx)) to download the update. You'll find that, after installing the update and restarting Visual Studio 2012, you’ll be able to create a new ASP.NET MVC 5 application through Visual Studio 2012.

Note that you may need to take care about which version you download for offline installation as, I think, there are different versions for the full/regular Visual Studio 2012 as opposed to the Express for Web. However, if you use the Web Platform Installer, then it should be able to sort this out for you.

The update not only provides the necessary foundation for creating MVC 5 applications, but it features the following additional improvements as well:

- Web API 2 Templates
- Entity Framework 6
- Razor Editor Improvements
- Improved Scaffolding
- Bootstrap Integration
- New NuGet

Comment: I don't have the change authentication button. How do I get the individual accounts code?

Comment: Hmm, good point, I didn't delve too long into it before. Unfortunately, this functionality appears to be introduced exclusively within Visual Studio 2013. I guess if you are using an older version, then it'd be necessary to use the standard ASP.NET Simple Membership, but I don't know anything about that (I started using this technology with VS2013 and Web API 2). This is all part of the "One ASP.NET" push that MS have done to combine multiple technologies together, like MVC, Web API, Identity, SignalR, etc.